# Rails how to select attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my controller I have:

```
def search
  @kategoris = Kampagner.where("titel like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
  @kate = []
  @kategoris.each do |kat|
    h = {}
    kat.attributes.each{|k,v| h[k] = v.respond_to?(:force_encoding) ? v.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") : v }
    @kate << h
  end
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @kate }
  end
end
```

But the problem is just that all of the attributes for the model are in the JSON data. I only what the attributes ID and title to be in the JSON data. How do I select this?

Comment: you use each when you should be using map (and do it in the controller when you should do it in the model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very clear why you want to use force_encoding. But you can simply just call:

```
format.json { render :json => @kategoris }
```

Rails will call the method as_json behind the scene. Then in the Kampagner class you can customize the as_json class to control what will be exposed when the record was exported to JSON:

```
class Kampagner
  def as_json(options={})
    super(options.merge({ :only => [:id, :title]})
  end
end
```

See more: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Comment: What if you have to render multiple JSON data for this same model but with other attributes what is the best solution for that?

Comment: Then I just use the only option :)

Comment: It's a good question. As I know, there is no best way for this, because it depends on what you want to export JSON for. You can write multiple export JSON methods inside the model class. Or customize the as_json with switch..case statement. Then just change the params passed to the to_json or as_json method. More thoughts?

Comment: user.as_json(:only => [ :id, :name ])]

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
@kategoris.each do |kat|
  @kate << kat.sanitized_whitelist
end
```

In model:

```
WHITE_LIST_ATTRS = [:id, :title]

def whitelist
  WHITE_LIST_ATTRS.each_with_object({}) {|attr, hash| hash[attr] = send(attr) }
end
```

or consider some dedicated method:

```
def sanitized_whitelist 
  WHITE_LIST_ATTRS.each_with_object({}) {|attr,hash| hash[attr] = send(attr).respond_to?(:force_encoding) ? send(attr).dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") : send(attr) }
end
```

Comment: just replaced the code with your´s and the now the json data is just empty: [{}]

Comment: I have also added the whitelist to my model. And just added     kat.whitelist but then again it is empty..

Comment: Still the json data is empty. I tried the to_json method replacing and it worked.

Comment: I don' know if you force encoding using to_json, updated the answer btw

Comment: whitelisting is simpler using active_support: `hash.slice(*keys)`